# Incidence geometry in 3 dimensions from Euclidean and non-Euclidean geometries by Marvin Greenberg

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

**The Question**

> Prove: If each of two intersecting lines is parallel to a third line, then the three lines are coplanar

**My Attempt**

This exercise appears in *Euclidean and non-Euclidean geometries* by Marvin Greenberg. I tried combining between

> **Theorem:** if there is a line and a point not on the line then there is a unique plane containing them

and

> **Corollary:** two parallel lines have a unique plane containing them.

but yet couldn't figure a way to prove this completely.

Comment: If a and b are those two lines that intersect at a point, say point A and if p is that third line, then isn't the plane defined by A and p the one that contains all three lines?

Answer (score 1):

If two lines $a,b$ intersect in a point, let's say $P$ and are parallel to the same line $c$ then we must have $a\equiv b$ for the Fifth Postulate, since the parallel is unique.

Plus for the first axiom, the line $c$ contains two distinct points $Q,R$.

Thus they are coplanar since three not collinear points $P,Q,R$ lie in the same plane (axiom).